# VS - Test Detail Summary Standard Output

Tags: visual-studio, test-explorer

I just updated Visual studio from 16.8.2 to the newest version. After running a test, Test Detail Summary got "Standard output" section which wasn't there before. My problem is that this section is annoying to me and I am not capable to turn the logs off at the moment.
For unit test that has about 300 data rows - the test logs contains about 300.000 rows of logs. Is there a chance to remove "Standard Output" from test results? Or at least replace it? It used to be in "Output" section before.