# How to show Console.WriteLine (Standard Output ) in Test Detail Summary in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, test-explorer

I updated to Visual Studio 2022 recently (currently on version 17.1.6 on Windows 10) which has as a feature that it will show Standard Output or Console.WriteLine output in the Test Detail Summary. See [Tips and Tricks - What's new in Visual Studio 2022 for Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/visual-studio-visual-studio-2022-launch-event/tips-and-tricks-whats-new-in-visual-studio-2022-for-testing), which has this segment at 2:58
[image: Console.WriteLine in test summary]
[image]

Unfortunately when I am running tests via Test Explorer I am not getting that Standard Output section of the test summary. Is there a setting or an update I need to enable that feature?

I suppose I am basically asking how to do the opposite of what this question is asking: [VS - Test Detail Summary Standard Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69118029/vs-test-detail-summary-standard-output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to display the Standard Output section in the test results without a third party dependency. However if you are using `XUnit`, you can add a reference to `XUnit.Abstractions`, which supports an `ITestOutputHelper`. Using your OutputHelper you [can write values directly to that Standard Output](https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output) using its `WriteLine` method.

```
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

public class FileTester
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;

    public FileTester(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        this.output = output;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async void ParsesFile()
    {
        // arrange
        var fileName = "TestFile";
        var outputFolder = Path.Combine("C:\Temp", fileName + ".txt");
        output.WriteLine(outputFolder);
        
        // etc.
    }
}
```

[image: VS Test Detail Summary - Standard Output]